# What is the difference between a variable declared in a method and a field declared as a class variable?

Tags: java, variables, methods, field

Im studying for an exam and im stuck at one question that i cant figure out.

The question is: ''What is the difference between a variable declared in a method and a field declared as a class variable?''

Can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: This is a fundamental question that is easily answered with a simple web search.  That type of question is off-topic here.

Comment: Variables normally only exist for the length of the scope in which they are declared, so a variable defined in a method will only *live* for the live of the method, and a field will leave for as long as the *class* lives

Answer (score 0):

As other people commented this is a basic stuff with variables in a programming language. In java there are types of variables, namely:

1. Local Variables
2. Instance Variables
3. Static Variables.

The variables declared within a method is called a local variable. The life of this variable is inside the method and is not accessible when the method is executed. These variables need to be instantiated when they are declared.

On the other hand, the variables declared outside the method but inside the class are called as Instance variables. These variables become accessible when an object is created for the class. The life of the variables is dependent on the life of the object.

Finally, static variables are same as instance variables but with the "Static" keyword. By the concept of static, they are created when the class is loaded. These can be directly accessed using the classname or the object reference. Only one set of static variables are created for every class. But in case of instance variables, each time you create an object, a set of instance variables are created for that object.

You can find a lot of online resource for this topic, I suggest you refer http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variables-in-java/.